# How to connect two JFrames in netbeans without using swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jframe

I am make a project on cars. How can I make distributor frame popup and cars frame not visible and close automatic? Kindly send any solution in simple and effective way.
I have done coding this way:-

```
    {
      Cars frm1=new Cars();
      Distributor frm2=new Distributor();
      frm2.setVisible(true);
      frm1.setVisible(false);
      frm1.setDefaultCloseOperation(frm1.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }
```

Comment: `JFrame` _without_ using `Swing`... hmmm.

Comment: `How to close a JFrame and open another after pressing a JButton?`

Comment: `javax.swing.JFrame` - Any idea what you're talking about ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *".Please help me to how I can make distributor frame popup and cars frame is not visible and close automatic."*

Ok so in Netbeans GUI Builder, you may want to do the following (this is assuming you have created two separate `JFrame` form files

- In the frame that is the launching program (we'll call it `MyFrame1`) add a button to it (we'll call it `jButton1`)
- Add a listener to the button, then the following code should be auto-generated

  ```
  public void jButton1ActionPerforemd(javax.swing.ActionEvent evt) {

  }
  ```
- In that `actionPerformed`, just instantiate the second frame (we'll call it `MyFrame2`) and `setVisible(false)` to `MyFrame1`. `MyFrame2` should already be visible upon instantiation, so you wouldn't have to `setVisisble(true)` on it

  ```
  public void jButton1ActionPerforemd(javax.swing.ActionEvent evt) {
      MyFrame2 frame2 = new MyFrame2();
      MyFrame1.this.setVisible(false);
      // You can also use  MyFrame1.this.dispose(); dependind if you ever need to use that frame again
  }
  ```

I think this should work

Answer (score 0):

you need to setVisible Jframe2 as true...so it can apear on output sceen

```
public void jButton1ActionPerforemd(javax.swing.ActionEvent evt)
{
   myFrame2 frame2=new myframe2();
   myframe1.this.setVisible(false);
   frame2.setVisible(true);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

create action event for the button such that when when you click will take 
   you 
    to the next page for my case next page is nextjFrame

```
private void nextButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

setVisible(false);

nextjFrame ob=new nextjFrame();

ob.setVisible(true);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private void BTNConvertActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

    /*
    This is the action performed event for my Button "BTNConvert"
    */

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater
    (new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            new JFrame2().setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    /*
    This will set the second Frame Visible.
    */

    JFrame1.this.setVisible(false);

    /*
    This should set the first frame invisible or whatever. Any other code should be 
    written before the curly brace below.
    */

} 

//You're Welcome.
```